# in MySQL how to do broaden the search

Tags: mysql

need to search by including terms to  more result set of relevant

broaden the search by using scenario
Table Below

| Title |
| --- |
| Introduction to MySQL |
| Getting Started with SQL |
| MySQL vs. PostgreSQL |
| Advanced SQL Techniques |
| Web Development with Python and MySQL |
| Data Modeling and Design |
| Troubleshooting MySQL Performance |

if user search MySQL

i need result like this

| Title |
| --- |
| Introduction to MySQL |
| Getting Started with SQL |
| MySQL vs. PostgreSQL |
| Advanced SQL Techniques |
| Full-Text Searching in MySQL |
| Web Development with Node.js and MySQL |
| Troubleshooting MySQL Performance |

result dont have `Data Modeling and Design` as it dont have SQL

Hope Like dint work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain in detail what it is you're trying to do and include what code you have and sample data.  What is your question?  As stated, your post isn't clear.  Broaden what search?

Comment: @ewokx   table given

Comment: Mysql fulltext search / pattern matching features are not mind readers. These will never guess that search expression mysql should also match sql without my.

Comment: @Shadow so there is no option for this.

Comment: How is it possible for a search result to include that SQL when you specify "MySQL"?  (akin to what @Shadow pointed out)

Comment: Also, this probably would be more suitable for dba Stack Exchange.

Comment: @geroge if you provide both mysql and sql in the search critetia, then it is possible. But you cannot generalise the query, i.e. if you search for postgresql, then it will not find rows containing sql - unless you manually cater for that one as well. Please note, no database product has google's search engine features built in. What you are seeling is called semantic search, when words with similar meaning are also included in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE MATCH(title)AGAINST('MySQL' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

for full-text search, need to do `full-text index` for the columns you to search
for eg:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name  ADD FULLTEXT INDEX title_fulltext_search (title);
```

[for more kindly click here for official doccuments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Query expansion takes words from rows identified in the first pass and uses those in subsequent passes for further searches. The word sql does not occur alone in any of the rows that have mysql. Also, quey expansion will return a lot of other rows as well.

Comment: @Shadow it works for me, whats error explain pls.

Comment: Then you must have other rows in your dataset that connect the rows that have mysql and just sql. Query expansion is not a magic bullet either.